# How to append javascript variable to html script tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some javascripts where I need to have a variable hostname since I will run my scripts in dev, test, and prod. How do I get a variable hostname into the javascript script tag?

I can't build this script tag using javascript itself. The example below doesn't work. What does?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
var hostname="sample.com";
</script>
<script src="https://" + hostname + "/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can dynamically add your script to your page after building the full scr URL. Here is an example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <script>
    var hostname = "sample.com";
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = hostname + '/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js'
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Otherwise:

You can dynamically add your script to your page after building the full scr URL. Here is an example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <script src="%HOST_NAME%/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="%HOST_NAME%/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="%HOST_NAME%/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var hostname = "sample.com";
    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    [ ...scripts ].forEach(script => {
      script.src = script.src.replace('%HOST_NAME%', hostname);
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank u, but i have too many script tags in my html page, so i cant build all these script tags using javascript.

Comment: You can if you factory that into a function to add a script to your page. Otherwise you can parse all of your script tags on page load and replace the src attribute with the new one. If you want to change only some script tags you can use class attributes to target only the one that need to be updated

Answer (score 0):

You can give an id to the `script` tag and then do something like this

```html
<script id="scriptID" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
const hostName = "sample.com";
const scriptTag = document.getElementById("scriptID");
const newURL = scriptTag.src.replace('ajax.googleapis.com', hostName);
scriptTag.src = newURL;
```

Comment: this completely generates new url right, but i just need to replace only "https://ajax.googleapis.com"

Comment: @GaneshPutta I have edited the answer, see if it helps :)

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>
            <a href="" id="link"></a>

            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
                var hostname="sample.com";
                //javascript 
                document.getElementById("link").href = hostname;
                //jquery code 
                $("#link").attr("href",hostname);
            </script>
        </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Register your script using javascript itself. you can use like this

```
var hostName = 'http://sample.com/js/';

$(
  '<script />', 
  { 
    type: 'text/javascript', 
    src: hostName + 'yourJSfile.js'
  }
).appendTo('head');
```